# Remove modifier from linked object via Python

Tags: python, modifiers, blend-files

**Blender version**: 2.9 and above (but probably going back to 2.8).

**Workflow**:

1. Object linked from separate file.
2. Library Override added to linked object
3. Modifier added to override object
4. Python Script attempts to remove said modifier

**Resulting error**:

```
Operator bpy.ops.object.modifier_remove.poll() Cannot edit modifiers coming from linked data in a library override | Error in execute function of DeleteArray
```

I'm struggling with this, because the same modifiers I'm trying to remove via Python, but can't, I can manually delete in the user interface.

Comment: I just tested and it works `obj.modifiers.remove(mod)`. Are you sure you are not trying to remove a modifier that was originally on the linked object ? Could be helpful to post a snippet of your code

Comment: Hi! I was using `bpy.ops.object.modifier_remove(modifier="Array", report=False)` on the active object. I wasn't aware of the method you posted, but it works! Thank you very much. (P.S. I was definitely doing this on a modifier added after the override, but your way works with modifiers that came from the linked source file too!).